# Issue in forwarding the control to a specific class in C# bot framework v4 for Luis

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am using V4 bot framework and on recognizing particular intent , i want to forward the flow to a specific class.

In V3 the forward(invoke className from current class)  was done using :

```
await context.Forward(new className(), ResumeControlAfterClass, context.Activity, CancellationToken.None);

...
...

  private async Task ResumeControlAfterClass(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
        {
            context.Wait(MessageReceived);
        }
```

Corresponding api for v4 is :

```
return await stepContext.ReplaceDialogAsync(
        nameof(WaterfallDialog),
        cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

I am trying below approach:

```
await stepContext.ReplaceDialogAsync(nameof(className), list, cancellationToken);
```

But,its not working and also i am not sure about list in the argument.

Please Help.

Comment: Are you getting any error

Comment: Its throwing exception message in bot emulator: The bot encountered an error or bug.

Comment: I would suggest you to refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-dialog-manage-complex-conversation-flow?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp and https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.core-bot